# Trying to Reference a Button With a String

Tags: java, android

I have a situation in an app I'm making where I have an activity that has 15 buttons and a string[] that contains 15 strings. I'm looking for an easy way to assign each string in the string[] to its corresponding button. I was hoping I could somehow do something like:

```
for(int i; i<myStringArray.length; i++){
    String ref = "btn" + (i + 1);
    ref.setText(resultString[i]);
}
```

where all the buttons are labeled "btn1", "btn2", etc so that they could all be accessed with the string "ref". Obviously this doesn't work so I was wondering if there was another way of doing something similar to this instead of doing:

```
btn1.setText(resultString[0]);
btn2.setText(resultString[1]);
btn3.setText(resultString[2]);
...
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: a possible way would be to put all these buttons into an array and loop through it....

Comment: Create a `HashMap<String,Button>` then simply run your loop and get `button` from map by passing the `string` and then use it to setText.

Comment: instead `Button btn1, btn2, btnN` use `Button[] btns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this by having a Button[] table where you store all your Button objects and then you can access them by index instead of the actual object name:

`Button[] btns = new Button[15]
for(int i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].setText(resultString[i]);
}`

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Ofcourse you have to fill your `Button[] btns` with your objects first.

Comment: That's actually the best solution imo, as that links both arrays. Keep in mind tho that his button array starts at 1, oyu should change btns[i] as btns[i + 1]

Comment: @Nathan `i` represents the index of the table not the number in the object's name so the `btn1` is stored in `btns[0]` thats why in the for loop I call `btns[i]` instead of `btns[i+1]`

Comment: Indeed, but I assumed from op's example that the `String ref` he built (from i) was the direct text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you tried using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful). It would be way better in your case to store your buttons in an Array or a Map instead though.

Comment: Answering that other question of you: yes, "too broad" would be one legit close reason for that question.